# Is it ever correct to use "to English" as a verb?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

I've run into this usage several times, in the comments of sites like YouTube, usually as a joke in response to having one's grammar or spelling corrected. 
To paraphrase:

> I'll try to English better :)

Presumably implying that their English needs improvement through example, even if the original mistake had been a typo.
My question is, is there a serious context where using 'English' as a verb would be grammatically correct? Or maybe it's on its way to becoming a new word due to frequent incorrect usage?

Comment: Yes - see a number of dictionary definitions having _English_ as a verb at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/English

Comment: As you can see from the answers already given (which you could have found on your own by just consulting a dictionary—for that reason I have, for now, voted to put the question on hold as not displaying any research effort), _to English_ has a few established but _different_ meanings. You should probably clarify if you’re talking specifically about the use of _to English_ in the sense of ‘to speak/use English’. Since this usage of _to English_ has not generally made it into the dictionaries, I would say that’s an on-topic question. As it stands right now, though, it’s sadly probably off-topic.

Comment: http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1993/01/25

Comment: The answers below not withstanding, I would beg you to please never do it.

Comment: It's a tongue-in-cheek thing, like "I forgot how to cat".

Comment: Agreed, I could probably have found it if I'd searched a dictionary directly, instead I searched through google (which always works for more difficult words) and found nothing relevant. Cut me some slack, I'm new here :)
And I was mainly wondering whether the usage was as tongue-in-cheek as it seemed, or people were actually using an obscure meaning of the word, that's why I asked.

Comment: Basically, this question can be asked about any language name, where "I can't [language] today" is a phrase I've seen in many conversations and it meant something like "My brain is so tired today, I can't even speak my native language (or a language I'm normally fluent in) at this point". I presume it's highly colloquial, and I highly doubt that this meaning has made its way into an official dictionary. But who knows, languages evolve.

Answer (score 8):

The verb *English* in the sense of *to translate into English* dates to 1450, according to the OED. The sense of *to anglicize, to impart an English character to,* dates to 1711, that example having for object a musical form, the madrigal. The sense of *to impart spin on a ball* dates from 1875 and is flagged as a peculiarly American usage. These are all senses that are *not* flagged as obsolete or rare. So yes, its use as a verb is [current](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=english_VERB&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3).

Comment: With an earlier start date than in your link, ngram shows the peak usage was in about 1700, when the title page of translated books usually stated "Englished by John Smith". I suspect the small amount of modern usage (compared with in 1700) is mostly academic references to historical documents.. I have never seen or heard it in the last 50 years in British English in any other context. (Note, I don't play billiards/snooker/pool).

Comment: @alephzero, 1695 indeed shows a peak to .0001636467%, but considering that 1694 and 1696 show zero (when you set smoothing to zero), I am going to guess that the height of the peak is a function of the smallness of the denominator, the numerator most likely being just a single instance.

Comment: Thanks, I must have been searching for the word the wrong way, I kept getting irrelevant results and couldn't figure out if the verb existed or not. The usages you mention (besides the billiards one of which I have no idea) do sound kind of obsolete or obscure, or maybe they're from a dialect I haven't encountered (English is my third language).

Answer (score 5):

You may use "English" as a substitute for "anglicize", but in actual spoken English which would be generally understood, "to English" is a term used in billiards/pool, meaning to put a special spin on the ball. So, you almost certainly will be misinterpreted if you use "to English" instead of "anglicize" or "use English" or "put into English", or some such appropriate expression.

Comment: _English_ in billiards is a noun, not a verb. It's normal to _put some English_ on the cue ball. I don't think I've seen/heard _I Englished the cue ball_ and in the same way you get _put some side on the cue ball_ but not _side the cue ball_.

Comment: I've heard both- put some English on the ball, and english the ball. Outside of drunks at the tables, though, I've only heard "put some English", to express putting a spin on something to make it fit or whatever. A somewhat related expression in American is "Kentucky windage" (she shoots a bit high, so aim a bit low, in reference to a weapon, for example).

Comment: Fair enough - if enough drunks use it as a verb - then it's a verb. Just one of the joys of not being constrained to a set of real rules.

Comment: Perhaps to 'Australian' is to use bottom-spin.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "English" as a verb, one can use 'better' as a verb.

Consider :

"I'll try to ***better*** my English."

The verb form of English is ***'anglicize'***. But in your example - "I'll try to English better ." - the verb form 'anglicize' does not sound nice - "I'll try to '**anglicize**' better .". I think it is not advisable to use 'anglicise' here.

Answer (score -2):

Google, when it came into being was the name of a company, was used as a noun. But as time passed, it came to be used as a verb to mean searching a query on Google's website.

I believe, as an extention and inspiration English too is following the same course.